# get Paypal account holder's detail

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am developing app in iOS and android. I added PayPal feature into app.
I am displaying text box to enter receiver's email address.
Now the problem is that only US Account holder will be able to receive money through PayPal.

When user enters email address in text field i want to check that paypal account with that email address belongs to U.S. account holder or Non-U.S. account holder.

I tried to search this but couldn't find anything useful.
Is  there any way through which i can check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

@BSThakrar, I'm confused by your question.

Note that you, the creator of the app (or your employer), is going to be the recipient of any payments. As per the comments in `PayPalPaymentViewController.h`:

> // Get a client id from developer.paypal.com. The receiverEmail is the email address
>   // associated with the PayPal account that you used to log in to developer.paypal.com.

So you cannot change the `receiverEmail` without also changing the `clientId`. But the `clientId` will presumably be hardcoded into your app.

In other words, the PayPal iOS/Android SDKs are *not* designed to be used for transfers of funds between two third-parties.

Apart from that, there is *not* a restriction that your `receiverEmail` PayPal account must be a U.S. account. See [Country & Currency Support for PayPal REST API Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/) for a list of the countries and currencies currently supported.

Comment: I am able to change receiver's email. And when i ran it in sandbox it runs fine. Money is transferred to the email address which i have specified not to the account from which i created the app. The link you specified is for PayPal REST API. The same applies for mobile SDK or SDK has separate list of supported currency. I tried MXN(mexican) which is in the link but still app is crashing in iOS.

Comment: when receiver's email is non-US account holder money is not added to receiver's account.

Comment: @BSThakrar thanks for your follow-up information. There are a couple of interrelated issues here. First, the connection of `receiverEmail` and `clientId` I described is how the SDK *expects* to be used. At the moment, Sandbox will not necessarily enforce all the rules that are enforced on Live. Also, for the moment, PayPal payments and credit card payments may not follow the same rules (i.e., one form of payment might send the funds to the account corresponding with the `clientId` while the other from sends the funds to the account corresponding with the `receiverEmail`). [to be continued...]

Comment: [...continued] These differences will change in the future as the SDK and the server software are each updated. However, as long as you always use the `receiverEmail` associated with your `clientId`, all should work fine. [to be continued...]

Comment: [...continued] Second, because the SDK uses the REST APIs internally, the currencies and countries listed in the above link should work for you when using the SDK. **If they do not work (for a case where `receiverEmail` and `clientId` correspond), then we definitely would like to know! Also, if you are getting the app to _crash_ rather than simply display an error message (even if using non-matching `receiverEmail` and `clientId`), please give us all the details -- we certainly consider _any_ crash to be a bug that needs fixing!**

Comment: Even if receiverEmail and clientID correspond app crashes when i use MXN currency.

Comment: @BSThakrar, using MXN currency with US accounts on Sandbox, the transaction goes through fine for me, without crashing. I'm using the latest release of the SDK, version 1.2.0, which was uploaded last week. Please feel free to provide further details about your crash (e.g., at precisely what point in the flow the crash occurs, and the contents of your console log) here, or else you can email me directly (dgoldman, located at ebay).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36811/discussion-between-dave-goldman-and-bsthakrar)